# I need a clean copy of my dovecot conf.d/10-master.conf

Tags: postfix

I messed up my configuration of my master.conf file in Ubuntu 14.  I need a clean copy to install or a way to download a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the dovecot config file: http://www.dovecot.org/doc/dovecot-example.conf.  That should help you a ton.

Also, here's an example 10-master.conf: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JoeKun/debian-configuration-files/master/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-master.conf.